# Need to solve problems with not fully installed packages

Tags: server, apt, package-management, dpkg

I have problems with some packages (7 of them to be specific), and I can't solve this situation.

## What's the problem?

Packages not fully installed and impossible to remove (at least for me).

## What's my OS and what I do with it at now?

My OS is Ubuntu server 16.04. I Just have install it.

I also installed asterisk, openvpn, openSSH and shorewall among others.

## Some information about the problem

Everytime I install or remove package, it's show me an error message of not fully installed packages that I can solve in anyway.

When I execute, as a root user, the command "dpkg --remove openvpn", the result is that:

```
root@ubuntu-server:~# dpkg --remove openvpn
(Reading database ... 64768 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing openvpn (2.3.10-1ubuntu2) ...
warnings.pm did not return a true value at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper line 84.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper line 84.
dpkg: error processing package openvpn (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 5
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openvpn
```

And the same is for the packages:

- mime-support
- pcscd
- opensc
- openvpn
- shorewall
- grub-legacy-ec2
- initramfs-tools

I also look into the file **/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper** and founded out the line mentioned like the error line: ***use warnings;***

## What I already try to solve this?

1. Comment lines in **.posrm** and **.prerm** files of
   some packages.
2. Diffetent ways to uninstall those packages (dpkg, apt-get and apt remove, apt purge, etc.).
3. reboot system after apt-get update and apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/perl-base_5.22.1-9_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all perl-base_5.22.2-3_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Your first line is a URL, not a valid terminal command. Do you mean they should download that file, then run the commands on the second and third lines?

Comment: @NickWeinberg sorry. I have fixed it

Comment: Thanks for you reply! It solve the most part of the problem. Now I got this:
`sudo apt autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.22.1-9) but 5.22.2-3 is installed
 perl-base : Breaks: perl (< 5.22.2~) but 5.22.1-9 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f`
What I should do? Because I also still having troubles with **dpkg --configure openvpn** command. Thanks again

Comment: I edited my question. Please refollow the instructions